# why threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'

Tags: c#, automapper

i use automapper lib,for convert image to byte[] and byte[] to image in models

```
m.CreateMap<Image, byte[]>().ConvertUsing<ImageToByteResolver>();
m.CreateMap<byte[], Image>().ConvertUsing<ByteToImageResolver>();
```

when i fetch data automapper convert byte[] data to image but occurred error in convert data

```
public class ByteToImageResolver : ITypeConverter<byte[],Image>
{
    public Image Convert(byte[] source, Image destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        using (var memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(source))
        {
            using (var bitmap = Bitmap.FromStream(memStream))
            {
                return  (Image)bitmap;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Here's the error when I fetch data

[image]

But when converting `byte[]` to `image` the error does not occur
[image]

Comment: Please post the entire exception stack trace and exception message.

Comment: I suspect you're getting a GDI argument exception in the `Bitmap.FromStream` constructor which means you're not loading an image file correctly, or you're loading an image type that GDI does not support.

Comment: By the time your method returns, the inner most `using` is exited and you are disposing `bitmap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my problem with change convert code as this :

```
public Image Convert(byte[] source, Image destination, ResolutionContext context)
{            
    using (var memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(source))
    using (var bitmap = Bitmap.FromStream(memStream))
    {                    
        var img = (Image)bitmap;
        return (Image)img.Clone();
    }
}
```